# Transfer sharedpreferences from an app to another

Tags: android

I want to distribute an application in two versions: free and paid.
The app stores in the shared preferences a few configurations and high scores.

The concept is that the user that is happy with the free version, can download the commercial version.

The problem is that he should also automatically import all the preferences and high scores from the free version *if they are present*. Although it seems to me that mine is a rather common situation, it looks very difficult.

I thought to use `SharedId` on both apps. This leads to enormous security problems and, as I learned, it is not guaranteed to work. Apps may have problems writing their own preferences, that anyway end to be exposed to all the world. Also there is no real synchronization: the commercial app should check if the free app preferences and then import them, and finally work on its own version. After all SharedId seems useless.

Then, I explored the world of `Service` and `Content Providers`.

It looks to me like shooting to a fly with a cannon. If I understood well, with the Service I run a service, so I have to run a code to make the two apps talk together, and this might be very heavy on a small cell phone for an operation that is just "transmit 20 numbers once at the first run and then never more". Is it true that I have to install a service that listens to all requests, even if they come one single time every 10000 installs?

Even worse with Content Providers, that look to me very powerful if I want to export thousands of numbers and correlated information, but ask me to develop dozens of lines of code with a sql-like syntax, when I just want to share something like 30 integers one only time.

So, providing that if these are the only solutions, I will face them, before this work, does anyone have any other possible solution to migrate ONCE from an application to another a set of 10-20 very simple preferences? Or which of these three is the best choice?

And, if the solution is: export it to a text file, what is the best and most secure way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: why dont you just release the app with an in-app purchase that unlocks the full version. then you dont have to worry about importing anything

Comment: That's another solution, do you have any example or link where to understand how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: read here about using in-app purchases http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Comment: Any tutorial on how to use the new API 3.0? All I find refers to very old versions.

Comment: yes look under Version 3 in the link and you will see `Implementing the API` there is also a sample app that comes with the SDK